# Pipe two shell commands in C

Tags: c, shell, pipe, fork

I'm trying to execute `grep -o colour colourfile.txt | wc -w > newfile.txt` through a program in C, instead of using the command line.

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (void) {
    int fd[2];

    pipe(fd);

    if (fork()) {
        // Child process
        dup2(fd[0], 0); // wc reads from the pipe
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        execlp("wc", "wc", "-w", ">", "newfile.txt", NULL);
    } else {
        // Parent process
        dup2(fd[1], 1); // grep writes to the pipe
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        execlp("grep", "grep", "-o", "colour", "colourfile.txt", NULL);
    }
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: You don't specifically mention where your question is, what isn't working, etc.

Comment: `>` is an instruction to the shell, not an argument to `wc`; it tells *the shell* to open `newfile.txt` for write and `dup2()` it over to FD 1 before the `exec*`-family call. Thus, you need to implement that logic yourself as well.

Comment: Just like the pipe operator (`|`) is implemented by the shell, so is the output redirection operator `>`.  To emulate the shell command you present, your program has to implement the latter, too.

Comment: suggest learning about the function: `popen()` and its' application

Answer (score 2):

1. `if (fork()) {` means `parent process` not `child process`, see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html
2. You should handle `>` like `|` use `open()`

The following `code` could work:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (void) {
  int pipefd[2];
  pipe(pipefd);

  if (fork()) {
    // Child process
    dup2(pipefd[0], 0); // wc reads from the pipe
    close(pipefd[0]);
    close(pipefd[1]);
    int fd = open("newfile.txt", O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_WRONLY, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
    dup2(fd, 1);
    close(fd);
    execlp("wc", "wc", "-w", NULL);
  } else {
    // Parent process
    dup2(pipefd[1], 1); // grep writes to the pipe
    close(pipefd[0]);
    close(pipefd[1]);
    execlp("grep", "grep", "-o", "colour", "colourfile.txt", NULL);
  }
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: just one more small detail: if `fork()` returns a negative number, the OP could issue an error message and fail instead of producing an empty output file with no error.

Comment: These three lines are evil: `int fd = open("newfile.txt", O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_WRONLY, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
    dup2(fd, 1);
    close(fd);` — you previously defined `fd` as an array of 2 `int`; now you redefine it as a single `int` (in a block where you've already used the array variant).  That's pretty nasty.  I strongly recommend using a different name for one of the variables.  It would be courteous to report what failed to execute if either or both of the `execlp()` calls fails.